# index number of slides in Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hello I have created some slides in Ionic,at the end of them I have the pagination number,but the index number didn't show correctly.Here what I have done:
[image]

```js
@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;
proposals: Proposal[] = [];
  results_number: number;
  results_per_page_number: number;
  pages_total_number: number;
  page_current_number: number;
  proposal_index: number;
  pagination_label: string;
  is_loading: boolean = false;
  last_loaded_page: number = 0;

onScroll() {
    let slidesTot = this.slides.length();
    let activeIndex = this.slides.getActiveIndex();
    if (activeIndex > slidesTot - 2) {
      this.startLoadingIfNeeded(activeIndex);
    }
    this.updatePaginationLabel();
  }


  updatePaginationLabel(){
    this.pagination_label = this.slides.getActiveIndex()+1 + " di " + this.results_number;
  }


  startLoadingIfNeeded(index: number) {
    if (!this.is_loading) {
      if (this.last_loaded_page < this.pages_total_number) {
        let last_loaded_item = this.results_per_page_number * this.last_loaded_page - 1
        if (index > last_loaded_item - this.PRELOAD_THRESHOLD) {
          this.loadProposals(this.last_loaded_page + 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<ion-slides pager="false" spaceBetween="10" slidesPerView="1.9" centeredSlides="true" zoom="false"
    (ionSlideDidChange)="onScroll()" (ionSlideTap)="onScroll()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try changing the following lines:

```
updatePaginationLabel(){
 this.pagination_label = this.slides.getActiveIndex()+1 + " di " + this.results_number;
}
```

to this:

```
updatePaginationLabel(){
 this.pagination_label = this.slides.getActiveIndex()+1 + " di " + this.slides.length();
}
```

?

Maybe there is a miscalculation on the connection between `results_number` and slides actually created.